# "10%" is not a number for `lighten'

Tags: sass

Using this SASS:

```
$priamry-dark: #333;    

$nav-section-colors: (darkest, 10%) (darker, 15%) (dark, 20%) (medium, 30%) (light, 40%) (lighter, 50%) (lightest, 60%);

        @each $color in $nav-section-colors {
          .#{nth($color, 1)} {
            background: lighten($primary-dark, #{nth($color, 2)});
          }
         }
```

I get the error:

```
"10%" is not a number for `lighten'
```

If I manually type out `lighten($primary-dark, 10%)` it works just fine. Issue occurs with any percentage.

Comment: Not sure why you're looping through all those nav sections, when a single class or enclosing div ought to suffice.

Comment: I want a set of classes (.darkest, .darker, .dark, etc.) that I can apply to various sections of the project.

Comment: Thanks cimmanon, I was able to resolve it by simply not using SASS interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, removing the interpolation (#{}) and directly using the result of the nth() resolved my issue.

Thanks to cimmanon for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It is preferred that duplicates get closed as being duplicates, rather than answering them.

Comment: How can I mark it as a duplicate?